# HtmlUnit - Illegal Selector Error

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit to submit a form [here](https://nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm)

with the following code

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
  final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm");
  System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
}
```

but I get this error

```
Aug 23, 2018 10:50:35 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '#main_menu > ul > li:last' error: Invalid selector: *#main_menu > ul > li:last).] sourceName=[https://nseindia.com/common/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js] line=[100] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

The error comes in `jquery-1.4.4.min.js`. So it probably shouldn't be a code problem. Plus, I don't get this error when I try to access the web page on Chrome.

I also added the following but I still get the same error

```
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);
```

Could someone help me with this? I use `htmlunit-2.32` along with `Java 1.8`

**Update:** I also get the following warning many times before the actual error appears

```
Aug 24, 2018 11:16:55 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.`
```

Also, when I change the url to `https://stackoverflow.com`, I get another runtime error

```
Aug 24, 2018 11:41:53 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: *:x).] sourceName=[https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

but the code still moves forward and prints the page's title. In my case, the program doesn't terminate, but it doesn't move forward either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your error in chrome after reloading the page and very quickly executing the given invalid selector using chrome javascript console.
This leads me to beleive that the element targetted by the seletcor is created by javascript (which is actually confirmed if you search the selector in all the files of the page), which is why your code gives the error.
Try adding

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
```

just after the call to getPage. That should let your code wait for 3 seconds which should be far enough for the js to create the requested element.

A better approach would be to listen to some event like `onload` but I'm not sure of how this could be done from the client rather than from the page itself...

Comment: Didn't work for me. I even changed the time to 10 seconds (10000ms) or even 20.

I also get this warning before the error if it helps

`Aug 24, 2018 11:16:55 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your code:

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

It'll prevent `HtmlUnit` to throw an exception when any JavaScript fails.